# Handle a gunicorn worker termination from the FastAPI

Tags: python, signals, fastapi, shutdown, uvicorn

A FastAPI application restarts after gunicorn worker timeout. Is it possible to handle such a signal from the FastAPI application (`shutdown` signal doesn't help) before the application restart?

The problem is that some function exceeds the default time limit (30 seconds), which is ok, and we want to handle the situation by catching such a signal to notify a user about an error. Otherwise, the user will see `upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination`.

```
INFO [83] uvicorn.error Application startup complete. ()
CRITICAL [70] gunicorn.error WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:83) (83,)
CRITICAL [70] gunicorn.error WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:83) (83,)
WARNING [70] gunicorn.error Worker with pid 83 was terminated due to signal 6 (83, 6)
WARNING [70] gunicorn.error Worker with pid 83 was terminated due to signal 6 (83, 6)
INFO [83] gunicorn.error Booting worker with pid: 83 (83,)
INFO [83] gunicorn.error Booting worker with pid: 83 (83,)
INFO [83] uvicorn.error Started server process [83] (83,)
INFO [83] uvicorn.error Waiting for application startup. ()
INFO [83] uvicorn.error Application startup complete. ()
```

Unfortunately, a timeout increase isn't feasible.

I did try a `@app.on_event("shutdown")` and some FastAPI general exception handling methods, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

Gunicorn sends a `SIGABRT`, signal 6, to a worker process when timed out.
Thus a process, FastAPI in this case, needs to catch the signal, but `on_event` cannot because FastAPI(Starlette) event doesn't mean signals.

But there is a [simple solution](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-abort), Gunicorn server hooks.

```py
def worker_abort(worker):
   ...
```

> Called when a worker received the SIGABRT signal.
>
> This call generally happens on timeout.
>
> The callable needs to accept one instance variable for the initialized Worker.

Of course, you will lose the request at that time; you have to find another way to send response to users. I recommend using FastAPI `BackgroundTasks` or Celery.